# In CocoaLumberjack, how do I log a particular level of logs to file only?

Tags: objective-c, logging

Basically I self-define a custom log level and I want to log that particular level message to file only. I don't want messages of any other level to be logged to file at all. However, it seems that lumberjack does not provide this kind of extension.

I tried subclassing `DDFileLogger` and override its `logMessage` selector. However, doing this will result in each logs to be logged in a different log file. (That is, I will have a separate log file each time I log.) I am not sure how it ends up with this, and could not find a solution to this either.

Any other suggestions?

FYI:

**Platform**: iOS

**Subclassing** of DDFileLogger is as follow.

```
@interface BBFileLogger ()
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger logFlag;
@end

@implementation BBFileLogger
- (instancetype)initWithLogFlag:(int)logFlag logFileManager:(id<DDLogFileManager>)fileManager
{
    self = [super initWithLogFileManager:fileManager];
    if (self) {
        self.logFlag = logFlag;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)logMessage:(DDLogMessage *)logMessage
{
    if (logMessage->logFlag != self.logFlag) {
        return ;
    }

    [super logMessage:logMessage];
}
@end
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I figured it out. It's because the version of CocoaLumberjack I used is outdated (1.9.x). Updating the pod fixes this.